# HSQLDB: How to specify where a JAR file with a SQL/JRT function may be found?

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, hsqldb

I have the following CREATE FUNCTION code for a small function that I have written in Java.  It is a simple function that converts a Modified Julian Day number, a double, and returns that timestamp as a String.  I'd like to use this function to create a View in the Schema.

```
CREATE FUNCTION to_date_string(mjd DOUBLE) 
    RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
    LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
    SPECIFIC to_date_string_from_utc_mjd
    EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:org.kls.md.sqljrt.StringUtil.toFormat';
```

I've compiled this into a small JAR file.

How do I register this so that the RDBMS will be able to find and invoke the function?  I've tried putting this file in the same directory as the hsqldb.jar file, the server.properties file, the database files.  Feeling clueless.

I'm using Squirrel-SQL to execute SQL commands agains HSQLDB 2.3.0 snapshot 50 running in Server Mode on port 9001.  Here's the error message reported by Squirrel:

```
Error: user lacks privilege or object not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kls.md.sqljrt.StringUtil org.kls.md.sqljrt.StringUtil in statement [CREATE FUNCTION to_date_string(mjd DOUBLE) 
    RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
    LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
    SPECIFIC to_date_string_from_utc_mjd
    EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:org.kls.md.sqljrt.StringUtil.toFormat']
SQLState:  42501
ErrorCode: -26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply put it on classpath. In which jar JVM finds the class is the matter of classloader you use. If you need to specify the jar, [write your own classloader](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142%2Fhtml%2Fid1100.html).

Comment: hey guys, wait a second, I'm dying here, you .java class is in the classpath, but where do you put the previous block of function declaration: "CREATE FUNCTION to_date_string .... ".
where is this one put

Comment: Hi Eyad, you simply run that as a SQL query, same like you'd do with an `INSERT` query. I.e. JDBC's `executeUpdate(...)` IIRC.